# What is a good way to store multiple expansions of Dominion?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-prosperity, dominion-alchemy, dominion-seaside

At the moment I just have the base set of Dominion and Dominion-Intrigue, each of which are a full set so currently I'm storing each per the in-the-box organizers in their original boxes.

But when we buy another expansion (and more after that) I'm starting to wonder how we can best store all of these expansions. I've seen (but don't recall exactly where) various solutions for storing Dominion cards.

For us I think the following features would be needed:

- easy and rapid setup (so no need to resort piles beyond counting out the numbers of some cards per the number of players - which in our case is usually two)
- easy to clean up when the game is over and/or set up another game with a different set of cards
- consistency in how the cards are organized - I've noticed that the default organization structure changed between the Base set's layout and Intrigue (the base set alpha sorted while Intrigue sorted the cards into more categories before alpha sorting)
- Ideally space efficient so we can more easily travel with our games

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've actually seem some rather nice setups for storing Dominion cards on BoardGameGeek.  The standard I've seen is using card dividers and storing the cards in one of the original boxes with the insert removed.  Here are a few of the examples I've seen of what that looks like.

- One Game box containing multiple sets:  [Example Picture 1](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1008602/dominion), [2](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1008603/dominion), [3](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1008604/dominion) and [4](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1008605/dominion)
- Alternative Example with One Game Box:  [Example Picture](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/961211/dominion)
- Using two game boxes:  [Example Picture 1](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1023075/dominion) and [2](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1023076/dominion)
- Everything in one box, and a box for 5-6 player [Example Picture](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1014264/emteedee)
- Using just a what appears to be a random box:  [Picture 1](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/971337/dominion) and [2](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/971336/dominion)

Depending how many expansions you have, will depend on how big a box you end up needing.  If you're planning to get all of the current expansions, it looks like you'll run out of room if you're using just one game box.

Answer (score 19):

I got a 3,000 card box from the local gaming store and then printed off a cardstock set of tab dividers from Board Game Geek (I use the [Sumpfork tabs](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/59848/sumpforks-double-sided-dominion-tabs-for-all-expan)). All cards go alphabetically instead of by set, except for the cards common to all games. Prizes are stored with Tournament, because that's the only scenario in which you would need them.

To simplify setup of Victory/Curse cards, I change the direction of the cards. For Victory cards, the first 8 face forward and the second 4 face backwards so I can easily separate out the cards not needed for a 2 player game. I do the same with Curses: 10 forward, next 10 backwards, final 10 forwards. Estates get complicated; I do 8 forward, 4 back, then 4 sets of 3 alternating forward and back (for starting hands). I could do alternating sets of 7 Coppers as well, but I haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: +1 for storing them in TCG boxes.  Mine are in two long boxes (although I need a third for Prosperity + Cornucopia), organized by set and then alphabetically.  WAY easier to carry, and easy to setup and cleanup too.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to Sumpfork tabs.  I just moved to long boxes myself (one longbox for Dominion Big Box, another for Intrigue with room for more expansions), and I'm currently using poker cards for separators.  Sumpfork tabs will save me a lot of time designing my own.

Comment: I've been using one of those boxes, along with the sumpfork tabs for several years now, and it has worked out excellently. I currently have the following stored in the box:

Base Game,
Intrigue,
Prosperity,
Seaside,
Cornucopia,
Hinterlands,
2nd Edition Upgrade Pack for Base Game,
and all rulebooks, mats and tokens for the mentioned games.

I figure I have enough space left for probably three more full size expansions. That's with all cards sleeved with Mayday standard sleeves (not premiums).

Answer (score 5):

Go here for the divider cards for all the sets: http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/73412/double-sided-horizontal-dividers-for-dominion-hint

and for the perfect carrying case that you see in the first links picture: go to http://www.sciplus.com/p/STOREITALL-BOX_4254 - the STORE IT ALL BOX with removable dividers.

We currently have the cards to: Dominion, Intruigue, Cornucopia, Seaside, Hinterlands, and Prosperity all in one case, but I think it's going to be too tight to get our Dark Ages set in there.  Will probably buy another case to space things out a bit.  The divider cards are great as they are double sides, so you can arrange your tabs anyway you like.  All the rules are printed on them too for easy reference.

Answer (score 4):

I pulled the insert from one box, and put each set of 10 cards into a snack sized ziplock. My dominion box holds Dominion and Intrigue this way; I could probably fit a third if I got more card-sized baggies. Since this makes for easily grabbed sleeved cardsets, I can simply random grab-n-go for play.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a 1000 card box and used index card halves for dividers (longer than the card length). I have like 5-6 sets. I combined all the sets together and then separated first by purchase cost (6+ as one grouping) then by alphabet groupings like A-M, N-Z, etc. In this manner it cuts down on the time it takes to put cards away since you don't have to find things alphabetically, just by alphabet group. Plus if you know you want a certain cost card, the groupings are already separated by cost.

Coins/VPs/Curses/Prizes/Alchemy cards have their own groupings.

Answer (score 0):

I used a set of transparent wallet-size photo holders that I bought at the local pharmacy (which is an American notion of a store that sells everything from medications to cigarettes to food to school supplies). Each sleeve has 7 sections, and 10 cards fit almost OK into one section, but it is too tight for the green 12 card decks. I got 7 sleeves for my Basic + Intrigue sets, put the 49 stacks in, and the Gardens have to roam around with just the rubber band around it. The money and VP stacks are also in the rubber band format. That takes about half of the volume of one box. The photo holders are worn out after about 3-4 years of biweekly or so use, I have to say.

Answer (score 0):

My friends use binders with card sleeves.  Each page holds 9 sets of kingdom cards, and the only slightly fussy thing is splitting the money/curses/victory into piles of 10-15 cards to fit the sleeves.
I guess resorting the selector cards may be a pain if you have many sets, but it has mostly been a non-issue for us.  Additionally, you can store separated starting decks with little worry that they will get unsorted.